# Solving trigonometric derivative problems

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I have a function $F(θ) = \sin^{−1} \sqrt{\sin(11θ)}$

I derived the following answer using basic trigonometric and quotient rules.

$\dfrac{11\csc \left(\left(11\theta \right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)\cos \left(\left(11\theta \right)\right)}{2\sqrt{1-\sin \left(11\theta \right)}}$

My answer however is wrong. I am having a very bad time with getting the solution for it.

Can anyone outline how to go about getting the correct solution to a problem such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = u(\theta)$ and $F(\theta) = \sin^{-1}u$

Then $F'(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \dfrac{du}{d\theta}$

If $u = \sqrt{\sin(11\theta)}$, then

$\dfrac{du}{d\theta} = \dfrac{11 \cos(11\theta)}{2 \sqrt{\sin(11 \theta)}}$

So
\begin{align}
   \dfrac{dF}{d\theta} &= 
   \dfrac{11 \cos(11\theta)}
         {2 \sqrt{1-\sin(11 \theta)} \sqrt{\sin(11 \theta)}} \\
   & = \dfrac{11 \cos(11\theta)}
             {2 \sqrt{\sin(11 \theta)-\sin^2(11 \theta)}} \\
\end{align}

It might be worthwhile to comment that 
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(11\theta)}}
=\sqrt{\csc(11\theta)}$